# .bat file to open executable within Console2

Tags: batch-file, console2

I am aiming to create a .bat launcher that will execute a command line .exe program within [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).
My best guess would be that it should go something like:

```
@echo off
start "" Console.exe program.exe
```

but all that does it open Console2.
Please note that all .bat, and executables are all in the same folder.

Comment: Have you looked the docs for console.exe's command line syntax? Any clues there? Edit: The docs don't seem to work... You'll have to look in the source I suspect

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok I looked in source for the Console.exe and drilled down into the compiled help.

You need a -r

So: `Console.exe -r program.exe`

```
Command line parameters

Console supports these command line parameters: 

-c <configuration file>
     Specifies a configuration file. 


-w <main window title>
     Sets main window title. This option will override all other main window title settings (e.g. 'use tab titles' setting) 


-t <tab name>
     Specifies a startup tab. Tab must be defined in Console settings.


-d <directory>
     Specifies a startup directory. If you want to parametrize startup dirs, you need to specify startup directory parameter as "%1"\ (backslash is outside of the double quotes) 


-r <command>
     Specifies a startup shell command. 


-ts <sleep time in ms>
     Specifies sleep time between starting next tab if multiple -t's are specified.
```

Comment: be sure to add quotes: -r "command". worked like a charm after that.

Answer (score 10):

I'd never heard of this program, but its [source code](http://console.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=console/console;a=blob;f=Console/Console.cpp;h=fbfdb75100561ace0e7e51b091d81b3908ccd927;hb=HEAD)

```
   else if (wstring(argv[i]) == wstring(L"-r"))
             {
                     // startup cmd
                     ++i;
                     if (i == argc) break;
                     startupCmds.push_back(argv[i]);
             }
```

makes it seem like you might want to try:

```
Console.exe -r program.exe
```